# Load .txt file from javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, text-files

I want to load a local .txt file and work with the content in javascript.
My local file is like C:\Users\Who\Desktop\file.txt
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable

Comment: i've seen it. but i want to get ir from my computer directly.

jQuery.get('file://C:/Users/Luccas/Desktop/idades.txt', function(data) {
    var myvar = data;
});

seems not to work, only solution to place on server to get via ajax said under.

Comment: @Yacoby, perhaps he needs some advice/pointers?? An unfriendly response like this really steers people away from sites like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by default javascript is NOT allowed to access local file system for security reasons.  If you want to allow a particular script access to a local file then you have 2 options.

1a. Change your model, put the text file on a server and load from there...

1b. Run a local webserver :-)

2 ... this becomes browser dependent,

In particular,

- you can create a signed javascript for Mozilla like browsers, see http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html for details
- you can create an ActiveX plugin that allows local access for IE types... ;
- and for anything else again read up o local access.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, place it on a web server (on the same domain you are working on) then perform an AJAX GET.

```
var file = (function func1() {
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: file,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            result = data;
        }
    });
    return result;
})();
```

Comment: Not really true.  You can't load the text from file using javascript, but you could certainly get it to the javascript for processing.  See my answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use a number of back end solutions, I answered the question in the context of JavaScript, a client based solution,

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing by your question that maybe you're trying to do some form of JS templating. In which case, you'd probably want to look at something like this: http://github.com/andyet/icanhaz.js

The short of it is, you can store text that you want access to in JS in this way:

```
<script id="my_snippet" type="text/html">
    Whatever random text here, format doesn't really matter,
    you can use whatever unless  you're trying to serve it as xml.
</script>
```

It's actually valid in HTML 5. Then you can retrieve the contents in JS like so:

$('#my_snippet').html();

ICanHaz.js abstracts this all a bit for you so if you're templating... I'd recommend using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a WebBrowser control, use C# to load the .txt file contents into a div or something and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing a website to access c:\path\file.xxx on the client's computer is a major security breach.  Javascript will never have this functionality.