# NodeJS : Read csv file with pagination (i.e if it have 1000 files I will get 0-99 and on the call of next() I will get 100-199 and so on)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, readfile

### Brief Intro

I am developing server side application in NodeJS which include one module which read data from csv file and perform some task.

In CSV file data could be in Millions lines but at the same time I am having limited memory available.

To perform a task I am using [kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue) (creating a job per line)

currently I am creating jobs as soon as CSV reader give me dataand kue is keeping that job in memory and will not leave until it finish (So till the CSV reader finish reading file there is millions of job exists in memory).

So as a solution What I want to do is I read first few hundreds lines create jobs let `wait till it finish` then read another hundreds.

Here waiting is more important I can not use any module which allow me to read file line by line because in that case it will keep returning me liens and I will keep creating jobs.

I want control on reader such that when I get desired hundreds (ex 100) I will wait till all 100 will finish then ask reader to return next hundreds (ex next 100).

### Conclusion

I want to know how I can read few lines from a csv file then process it and then read remaining (Same is pagination).

Code will look something like below

```
const smartReader = required('snartReader');
smartReader.read(100,(data,next) => {
   performJobs(data); // wait until it finish then
   next(); // it will read next 100    });
```

### Declaration

I am not an experienced person in NodeJS and this is my first application.

Comment: Node supports [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream), you could also use [Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline)

Comment: Ya in that case how can I control stream I mean like if I want it to wait in half a way till i proceed remaining lines and continue and again wait for the same till I reach EOF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js)

Comment: As @Rafael pointed out streams are great and you don’t have to manage them, they manage themselves.  See this SO about streaming large JSON data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863329/nodejs-save-json-file/55864396#55864396

Comment: @ChrisAdams problem is not because i am reading large file problem is because i mean creating job as soon as i read a line.

Comment: Solution i thought was i will read few lines only at first then finish jobs then read next few lines

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [csv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) in npm? It's designed to work with large csv files.

Comment: @RichS its not about reading large file its about creating jobs in kue

Comment: Well, it's both actually. You want to stream a large part of your csv. the csv package is comprehensive. Not just reading csv files.