# Is there a way to import strings from a text file in javascript, meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a programm where I need to have long multi line strings. It's a pain to store them in the .js document, because js doesn't have multi line strings and I end up having a twice as long as the screen width line looking as ugly as "This is an example.\n"

Is there a way to have a txt file, from where I can import strings with new lines (or at least just import strings)?

Comment: More information about how you are rendering the string would be helpful. Is it html? Is it in a dialog box? What does the program do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Nope, definitely not a duplicate; this is much harder to do in Meteor and a feature that isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [meteor-yaml](https://github.com/jamesknelson/meteor-yaml) package makes this easy - it automatically loads any .yaml files in your project, parses them into JavaScript objects, and makes them available in YAML.data.

In my application I have some code outside of the meteor app that needs the same settings, so I prefer to have the config file outside of the meteor project directory.  Then I load the file like this:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
fs.readFile('<path to file>.yaml', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if(err) { 
    //Throw exception if the file is missing
    throw new Error("Missing config file")
  }
  else {
    //Read the file into a JavaScript object
    config = YAML.parse(data); 
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, the meteor-yaml package is a little out of date with how the meteor team wants node packages to be loaded now, so if you're using a recent version of meteor the package won't work out of the box.

I filed a [bug](https://github.com/jamesknelson/meteor-yaml/issues/2) about this, but in the meantime to get around it I installed it as a [private package](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration), as opposed to installing it from atmosphere, and fixed the bug.  To do this:

1. Clone the repo under your projects packages/ directory
2. Comment out the Npm.require lines.
3. Add a call to depends:

   Npm.depends({yamljs: "0.1.4"});
4. Run meteor.  Meteor will detect the meteor-yaml private package and install the dependencies.

Comment: Oh it appears it's for meteorite. I can't use that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, that reminds me - the meteor-yaml package has a silly bug that makes it not work with recent versions of meteor.  To get around it I installed it as a custom package instead of an atmosphere package.  I'll update my answer to include that info

Comment: Euphe - the instructions for installing it as a private package should work without meteorite.

Answer (score 7):

There is a Meteor `Assets` object that allows you to read files in the `private` directory of your app, in the following way for example for text files.

```
Assets.getText("foo.txt", function (err, res) { ... });
```

See full documentation: **http://docs.meteor.com/#assets**

Comment: The docs say that assets have to be static. Is there some way for me to load new files and get its text while the app is running?

Comment: You would need to serve those dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer works only for public files. If you want to access file data that is visible only on the server you should probably use 'fs' npm module. It's described in details here: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-file-uploader-part-2-server-side-save