# Flash CC HTML5 Canvas load from file/database

Tags: html, flash, canvas

im new to stackoverflow, so i hope im doing everything right here ^^

So to my Question/Problem:

Im working with Flash CC and made a small HTML5 Canvas Animation. In this Animation there is a Textfield where I want to load text from a file/database. Is this possible? I assume that I have to use javascript/json for that bec Flash CC Canvas is working with that. But can I code it directly in Flash (in the Actions Panel) or do I have to open the js-output file and put my code there? And are there any examples of that case?

Second, and a more specific case of that above, I want to load a specific text into my textfield for example:

lets say  I have a text in 3 languages (english, italian, french).
so I send a variable, where I state which language I want (var = eng;) and the correct text is loaded (from the file or database) to the textfield.

I hope everything is understandable (sry im not a native speaker)

Thanks in advance for any help/tips

Answer (score 0):

You can code that interaction directly into the .fla file if you like.
Here is a simple example that you can play around with:

1. Open a new blank HTML5 Canvas Document in Flash
2. Create a text field and button and give them the instance names of text_box for the text box and btn for the button.
3. paste the following code onto frame 1 on the timeline:

   ```
   //Variables
   var count = 0;
   //Make browser listen for a mouse click on the button
   this.btn.addEventListener("click", fnCycleLang.bind(this));

   function fnCycleLang()
   {
    if(count == 0){
       this.text_box.text = "Hello World!"; //this actually changes the text in the text box
       count ++;//this adds 1 to the count
   }
   else if(count == 1){
       this.text_box.text = "Bonjour Le Monde!";
       count ++;
   }
   else if(count == 2){
       this.text_box.text = "Ciao Mondo!";
       count = 0;
   }
   }
   ```

When you publish the .fla to HTML5 you should be able to click the button to cycle through the different languages. This way may be a but code intensive but it depends on how much text you are going to need to swap around. This would be fine for something like some menu items. Anything with a lot of text you would probably be better off not using flash to author it for you.

Comment: Hey Malco, thanks alot for that.
But, is it also possible to get the textes "Hello World", "Ciao Mondo!" etc. from a file (like xml) or a database?

Comment: Check out this question here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: The answers in the above link do a better job explaining it than I could. The only thing to remember is that when you are working in a HTML 5 Canvas document, flash is outputting pretty much only JavaScript so most anything you could do in a separate .js you can do on a frame in flash. Just be careful about variable scope as any thing you write will be nested inside the different frame functions on output.