# Is it possible to link js array source to a text file prsent in server

Tags: jquery

I have got nearly 6000 symbols of array symbols for example inside my  js file

```
var sourcesymbols = [
    "ONE",
    "TWO",
    -------- upto 6000 symbols 
]
```

Rather than defining this array in jsfile, is it possible to link it from sever (for example i have got a txt file in server and now can i provide it as a source to this array)

something this way

```
var sourcesymbols = http://localhost:8080/RESTWEBAPP/myfile.txt
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Ajax example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Or you could just save the files as a .js and include it.

Comment: What's the format of data inside your myfile.txt?

Comment: Thanks for the second option that looks a better approach