# Load text from local .txt file into html textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` element and a button that calls a `loadFile()` JavaScript function. I want this function to allow me to load the text from a .txt file on my local machine into the textarea. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the File and FileReader objects to read local files.

You can use an input element with type="file" to allow the user to select a file.

```
<input id="myFile" type="file"/>
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="4" columns="20"></textArea>
```

After the user has selected a file, you can get the File object from the input element. For example...

```
var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
```

You can then use a FileReader object to read the file into the text area. For example...

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
    textArea.value = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a old topic about this:
[How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Have you read the last answer already? This works with a div instead of a textbox, but you could adapt the code a bit.

In the last piece of the last commenters post you could change this line:

```
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("textbox01").innerHTML = out;
```

And in your HTML:

```
<textarea name="textbox01">Enter text here...</textarea>
```

Result:

```
function loadFile() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "file.txt";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);

            console.log("xmlhttp Request Asepted");
        }


    }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


        function myFunction(arr) {
            var out = "";
            var i;
            var row = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           // console.log( arr[1].data); change data to what every you have in  your file
           // out +=  arr[i].data + '<br>' + arr[i].data2 ;
            document.getElementById("textbox01").innerHTML = out;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this imports the text file from a url (i.e. a server) rather than my local machine

Comment: You could use USBWebserver as a localhost server, this is what I do when I need to make use of cookies.

Comment: Regardless, this is not addressing the question, nor the context.  Context is a _local file_, meaning from the computer you are on, from the filesystem, not a server, nor a "local" server.

Comment: @jdmayfield I don't think it's useful for anyone to reply on an answer almost 7 years after the question has been asked.

Comment: @iSidle Even when it's a better answer?  Question is still pertanent.  I found this looking for a solution to the same issue, and none of the answers were a viable solution to my problem.

Comment: @jdmayfield I think, in theory, it should even be possible to save this js to a HTML file locally using a script tag and then use file:// to reference your file using an url. It is just a matter of how you interpret the question, the author of this topic never specifically specified he wants other users to be able to upload a txt file.