# Fill a textarea with the content of a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I create a textarea and then I want, with Javascript or what I need, to fill the textarea with a content of a file, when I clicked a button.

How can I do that, or what do I need?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: Make an ajax call, read the file with php, send it back to Jquery (or vanilla), change the content of textarea with the data received. What have you done for the moment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the text already loaded into the page and held in a Javascript variable? If not, as other have suggested then an AJAX call may be required to retrieve this data.

Changing the value of a textarea can be done with some simple javascript as below;

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<input type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="button" />

<script>
function changeText() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
  textarea.value = "new Value";
}
</script>
```

If instead we're retrieving a file without jQuery the function can be as below;

```
function changeText() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'request_page.php');
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var status = 4;
        var http_code = 200;
        if (xhr.readyState === status) {
            if (xhr.status === http_code)  {
                var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
                textarea.value = xhr.responseText;
            } else {
                // do something with an error here
            }
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: How is this getting the contents of a file from the server into the text area?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Fixed my response.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. But how i have to do it, when my page is located: "/html/...php" and the file i want to fill "/doc/file.log"

Comment: @Noel007 You can provide a full path to xhr.open() to correctly open your file.

Comment: Okay I did it, now when I open my page, and click, I get to "// do somtehing with an error here" how can I fix that?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks, I quickly put it together. I've edited it now with your suggestion.

Comment: Another thing to point out is that this will only work if the file you want to read is under the document root (and you need to enter the URI to that file (from the document root), and not the full file system path.

Comment: Can I use it also with a dropdownmenu? EDIT: the file.log cant get with a URL only per full file system path

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for an ajax call. Javascript can call a page on the server that can open a file, read its contents and return in a json string containing the contents of the file, which the javascript then puts into the textarea

[Load text from local .txt file into html textarea using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640325/load-text-from-local-txt-file-into-html-textarea-using-javascript)

Comment: This is just a comment, please dont put comments in answer. They get downvoted, I did not downvote. You have enough reps to comment on any question!

Comment: why is it not an answer?

Comment: Does it actually solve or even attempt to solve the OP's question? No!

Comment: yes he asked what is needed to do something, and i suggested a way to do it, im not that bothered, i will delete the answer if you want me to

Comment: Its the first time for me to use Ajax, how I have to write it?

Comment: And now maybe you understand why I wrote what I did @noid Now you will have to write the OP's app for him :) _It was obvious from the start where this was leading_

Comment: i am fine with that, i thought though that we were not supposed to just give away completed code, but encourage learning.

Comment: @noid There you go. So basically this question is now definitely **Too Broad** and should be closed as such

Comment: well i learnt something here that i was not expecting, :)

Comment: @noid :) Well then its another good day :) :)

Comment: After a while you get to spot the _Code Vampires_ from a mile off

Comment: haha what a great visual.