# JavaScript load innerHTML out of file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a project with destructuring assignment for Menu Items in an own js file. The 'Menu point' is loading the HTML content out of the html_content.js file into the index.html file itself.
So

```
var html_content {
    "Menu point 1": "<p>html content for menu point 1</p>",
    "Menu point 2": "<p>html content for menu point 2</p>"
}
```

Is loaded via

```
gridWrapper.innerHTML = html_content[itemName];
```

into the HTML file. This is working fine, but now I want to load the HTML content out of a own file, something like

```
var html_content {
    "Menu point 1": "menu1.html",
    "Menu point 2": "menu2.html"
}

gridWrapper.innerHTML = <html_content[itemName]>; //load the HTML file here
```

I actually have no idea how to do that, my JS experience is very low.

There is another js file, I don't know if it's important for that, here's the [main.js file](http://hastebin.com/oqovogorav.js)

Comment: Have you tried `gridWrapper.innerHTML = html_content[itemName];` (vanilla javascript) or `gridWrapper.html(html_Content[itemName]);` (jQuery) at all?

Comment: @cale_b he still has to load the file in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: you are missing the = in the declaration of html_content

Answer (score 1):

To load the file in, you want to use `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/mypage.html');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  gridWrapper.innerHTML = client.responseText;
}
client.send();
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

or you can use jQuery, like so:

```
$(gridWrapper).load('mypage.html')
```

---

#### See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable) for more ways to load files.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can:

```js
var html_content = {
  "Menu point 1": "menu1.html",
  "Menu point 2": "menu2.html"
};


$(function () {
  $.get(html_content["Menu point 1"], function (data) {
    $('#gridWrapper').html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="gridWrapper"></div>
```

In Javascript:

```js
var html_content = {
  "Menu point 1": "menu1.html",
  "Menu point 2": "menu2.html"
};


window.onload = function() {
  var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', html_content["Menu point 1"], true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;  // if NOT request finished and response is ready
    if (this.status!==200) return;  //if NOT OK
    document.getElementById('gridWrapper').innerHTML= this.responseText;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="gridWrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to both files in the DOM then ajax is not necessary.

your index.html would look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
       <div id="menu"></div>


       <script src="menuItems.js"></script>
       <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

menuItems.js

```
var html_content = {
    "Menu point 1": "<p>html content for menu point 1</p>",
    "Menu point 2": "<p>html content for menu point 2</p>"
}
```

main.js

```
var menuElement = document.getElementById("menu");

for(var menuPoint in html_content) {
    menuElement.innerHTML += html_content[menuPoint];
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/0ump3nbe/)

Answer (score 0):

With `jQuery.load()` its easy:

```
$(gridWrapper).load(html_content[itemName]);
```