# How to Input and Output {Local text file} instead of using ActiveXObject (latest version of Chrome or IE 11) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function initMap() {            
      // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
      var RoundList = [
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 18.400, lng: -65.118},
          {lat: 19.551, lng: -60.164},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
      ];
```

What I'm going to do is load a local text file to change 【var RoundList】.

I've done the following Output methods:

```
function WriteToFile(text) {

        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        var f="c:\\test.txt";

        var s = fso.CreateTextFile(f, true);
        s.WriteLine('<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″ ?>');
        s.WriteLine(text);
        s.Close();
    }
```

It's useless in the latest version of IE or Chrome.

Chrome Gives an Error:

> (X)Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined.

IE does nothing!

Does anybody know how to implement Input and Output text file? Please help me to figure it out, I'm appreciate!

Comment: Marking "Solved" in your question title is not the way to close a question. Please mark an answer as accepted, or post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Saving text in a local file in Internet Explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Thanks to @Edward Z. Yang, who answered this question.

This method works on Chrome (Latest version) and IE (Latest version).

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick mark to the left of this answer, so it is marked as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand. Should I click my own answer  ??

Comment: [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) - yes, you may accept your own answer, if this was the solution.

Comment: Thanks @halfer !! I got it.