# Load local xml file and show in html5 page

Tags: javascript, html

i need to load a local xml file(ie: c:\temp\sample.xml) into local html5 page and show the result variables.

this is  sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fe:Invoice>
    <cbc:ProfileID>1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>FV341375</cbc:ID>
    <fe:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>2</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
        <fe:Party>
            <fe:Person>
                <cbc:FirstName>Andres</cbc:FirstName>
            </fe:Person>
        </fe:Party>
    </fe:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <fe:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1102347224825331</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <fe:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Item Description</cbc:Description>
        </fe:Item>
        <fe:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">65000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
        </fe:Price>
    </fe:InvoiceLine>
</fe:Invoice>
```

i need to print the values for:

- fe:invoice-> cbc:ID
- fe:invoice-> fe:AccountingCustomerParty -> fe:Party -> fe:Person -> cbc:FirstName
- fe:invoice-> fe:InvoiceLine -> fe:Item -> cbc:Description
- fe:invoice-> fe:InvoiceLine -> fe:price -> cbc:PriceAmount

**the result on my html5 page must be something like this:**

Invioce Id: FV341375

First name: Andres

Description: Item Description

Price:  65000.00

How i can do this using javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question DOESN'T follow the guidelines to submit one and is too specific I will still answer it.

Steps:

1. Load file from disk.
2. Display file structure
3. Parse the file
4. Display results

Implementation:

HTML:

```js
function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.textContent = contents;
  parse(contents);
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
  
var xmlDoc;
function parse(content)
{
  //Create a parser
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content,"text/xml");
  //Parse!
  document.getElementById("ID").innerText = "ID: " + xmlDoc.evaluate("//ID",xmlDoc).iterateNext().textContent;
  document.getElementById("FirstName").innerText = "First Name: " + xmlDoc.evaluate("//FirstName",xmlDoc).iterateNext().textContent;
  document.getElementById("Description").innerText = "Description: " + xmlDoc.evaluate("//Description",xmlDoc).iterateNext().textContent;
  document.getElementById("PriceAmount").innerText = "Price: " + xmlDoc.evaluate("//PriceAmount",xmlDoc).iterateNext().textContent;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
<div id="ID">ID: </div>
<div id="FirstName">First Name: </div>
<div id="Description">Description: </div>
<div id="PriceAmount">Price: </div>
```

How I implemented them:

1. I used Paolo Moretti's code to grab the local file from the disk.
2. I created a xml document to parse using the DOMParser API
3. I parsed the xml with XPATH
4. I updated the values in the page

CREDITS: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

PS: Please ask more precise questions and remember to not ask someone to code your project.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i really don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do an XMLHttpRequest, which is also known as AJAX. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498) talks about it a little more and encourages using an AJAX framework to cover "interoperability issue".

Here's what it would look like.

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'c:\temp\sample.xml');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
   var response = client.responseText,
       parser = new DOMParser(),
       xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");

   //use the xml Doc however you want.
}
client.send();
```

More info:

- [DOMParser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)