# Scrolling Marquee with Multiple Text File Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, marquee

I have been trying to build a scrolling marquee using JavaScript to add to a game stream that highlights the most recent followers, subscribers, etc.  I am using StreamLabels which captures the gamertags of the most recent everything and places the data into a text file labeled for each. To start building this, I had to first make sure I could have a script that can pull the text and print the file data on the webpage. However, every Javascript code I find will not output the data on the screen.

I first tried ([How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)):

```js
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

and added `readTextFile("follower.txt");` to the webpage code. Upon execution, the page was completely blank for Chrome, IE, and Edge.

Next I tried ([How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)):

```js
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/follower.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
```

as well as the updated 2019 code found in the comments:

```js
fetch('follower.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Each ended the same as the first: with a blank screen.

Finally, I gave up on the read from text using Javascript and started looking at `<marquee>`, which as far as I know is an outdated and archaic way of doing it. The [code I found](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-editor/2135) incorporated a little Javascript for the scrolling and HTML/CSS to control the text.  I also included an `<object>` pull the text file into the code. What I finished with was:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.marquee').marquee({
      allowCss3Support: true,
      css3easing: 'linear',
      easing: 'linear',
      delayBeforeStart: 1000,
      direction: 'left',
      duplicated: true,
      duration: 25000,
      gap: 20,
      pauseOnCycle: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      startVisible: false
    });
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
  .marquee span { 
    margin-right: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    } 
  .marquee p { 
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-right: 1000px; 
    } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="marquee" height=20px>
<p>Recent follower: <object type="text/html" data="follower.txt"></object> // Recent donation: <object type="text/html" data="follower.txt"></object><p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this code works, however the `<object>` is doing some weird things with spacing and randomly not being visible until the second object shows up on screen. Additionally, there is at least a 40 pixel spacing vertically between the `Recent follower:` text and the `<object>`, with the text being quite low compared to the text data (see image below)[image: marquee].

I know there is something wrong with how I am doing each of the above codes, so any help would be greatly appreciated. My assumption is that using `<object>` may be the root cause of the spacing issues. I had also planned on trying to do a text conversion to add into this, but without any usable functionality, not sure how that will go.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with this quite a bit the last 24 hours or so, and doing a little more research, it appears the ability to use JavaScript to read text files in a local environment only (i.e. `C:\` drive, or local html, java code/scripts, and text documents) does not work. The problems are multi-faceted:

```
 - XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///path/file.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy
 - GET file:///path/file.txt net::ERR_FAILED
 - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on ...
```

I tried installing an extension to disable CORS (even from local files), but it did not work and continued to error. The `GET file` and `DOMException` errors generated on all three code types.

Today I tried using a couple of utilities, including `java.util.scanner`. Unfortunately, the same CORS error continued to generate.  So it appears that unless you are going to run Javascript read text scripts outside of a webserver, there isn't much hope there.

Fortunately, the Javascript `marquee` works, but I'll have to do some work to correct the spacing issues with the `<object>`, or figure out an alternative solution to using an `<object>`.