# Is there a way to get inner html of a file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to return a piece of html code in a react function. However, rather than copying the file I want and put it the concerned code in quotes, I would like to do something like :

```
my_func() {
   return doc.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

Where *doc* would be a reference to some other file like :

> ./path/myfile.html

Is there any method that allows me to do that? Or am I constrained to copy all the code in my file.html and put it in quotes in my return function?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.get for example, to get your file and parse the content :

```
$.get('./path/myfile.html').done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/