# How can I create a JavaScript function that replaces the innerHTML of a paragraph with the contents of a text file?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's suppose that I have 3 files: `~/html/display.html`, `~/data/text.txt`, and `~/js/script.js`. `display.html` has the following body:

```
<body>
  <p id="textblock">text</p>
  <script src="../js/script.js">
    loadTxt("../data/text.txt", "textblock")
  </script>
</body>
```

and `text.txt` contains the single line: `text line`

I want to know how I can make a function `loadTxt`, with the signature `loadTxt(path, id)` in script.js that takes the contents of `path`'s text file and replaces the `innerHTML` of the paragraph with the given `id` with said contents.

I've tried using `fetch` and xhtml, but I'm having trouble navigating them.

Please also let me know if my syntax is wrong in my HTML. I'm not super used to working with scripts and HTML yet.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Show what you tried. It may be a simple mistake

Comment: [At least one of these will work](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+fetch+for+text+file+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and get the response text.

```
function loadTxt(path, id){
    fetch(path).then(res => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = res.text());
}
```

Comment: Dupe. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Nice answer, congratulations for 10k :)

Comment: @RiwimoHerbs Thank you.