# Reading from & writing to files in same domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file

Say I have a website hosted via Bluehost or the like, at `example.com`. If I have a file stored at `example.com/a.txt`, how can I go about reading from this file? And, if I want to write a new string to this file, is it possible to do so, or is it impossible with JavaScript in the web?

Comment: You read it using ajax (XHR, fetch, whatever). You can only write to it with the help of server-side code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 1):

you could make a simple api using express and use `file-system` or `fs`
with that package you can do that with a single line after doing `const fs = require("fs");` :

````js
const constant = fs.readFileSync("path");  //read the file
fs.writeFile("path", "something to write", () => {
    //a callback func
  });```
````

Answer (score 1):

In short no. But you have workarounds:

You can open some folder for the public view:

```
static files - read only access (styles and javascript)
media files - read only access (pictures and other media)
some manually created url - to edit/create the file in the media folder
```