# How can I read text from a file on a web page

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a webpage, and on that webpage is a file called b.txt, (http://#####.###/b.txt), how am I able to get my DiscordJS bot to display the contents of b.txt (the file just says hilly in plaintext")

Currently I just have  `const txtfile = "http://example.ml/b.txt";`

And have a simple command to output the variable.

```
      client.on('message', message => {
          if (message.content === 'b') {
            message.channel.send(mcdonal);

          }
         });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can probably use a `XMLHttpRequest` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/196510/212869

Answer (score 1):

Install node fetch to your project with

```
npm install node-fetch
```

include it with

`const fetch = require('node-fetch');`
than you can in either load the file once if it is static in your variable or load every time in your message event handler with e.g.

```
fetch('http://example.ml/b.txt')
    .then(res => res.text())
```

See also https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch