# Find a word and in txt file and get the definition (the definition in the txt file)

Tags: html, input

I have a txt document with a definition first and then a meaning with ; in between :

```
Apple;blabla. Pear; blah blah. Banana; blahblie.
```

And now I want to write that if you search an input in an html file on "Apple" you will find "blabla". But I don't know which program I would do best and how?

Comment: Could you share more details and code sample?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+read+text+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text contents of the file,you can use a  element and have an event listener on it so it can tell when a file is added. With this, you can get the file as it will be the first (0th) item in the file input e.g. `textFileInput.files[0]` and you can get the text from it by using `.text()` on it. This will be an asynchronous operation so you have to use await (i.e. `await textFileInput.files[0].text();`)

If you are certain that the word will always contain no spaces or characters such as `.` or `;` as you are current using them as delimiters, you can use them to split the objects into arrays with `.split()`, (e.g. `"abc!def!ghi".split('!')` separates the string wherever it find an '!' into an array: `["abc", "def", "ghi"]`), we can also uses this to separate your text into an array of "word; defintion" strings and further split those where there is a ';' present. We can then store the words and definitions in a JS object, which will allow you to access them by the keys, in this case the words themselves as such: `object.wordName` or `object['wordName'].

You can add a new key:value pair to an object by doing `object['newWord'] = 'definition of newWord';`, then you can access the definition of newWord with `const textDefinitionOfNewWord = object['newWord'];`

Now you can have a search box paired with either a button that runs a function, or an event listener (I have demonstrated below) for when any key is pressed while in the search box. If when accessing the object['word'], it returns a non-null value, there is a definition stored that you can output.

```js
// dictionary will store the text later, after it is uploaded
// definitionObject will store words and definitions, accessible by word
let dictionary = "";
let definitionObject = {};

const textFileInput = document.querySelector('#textFileInput');
const textFileOutput = document.querySelector('#textFileOutput');

const searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchInput');
const definitionOutput = document.querySelector('#definitionOutput');


textFileInput.addEventListener('change', async function () {
    // set dictionary to be the text from the file
    dictionary = await textFileInput.files[0].text();
    // set textFileOutput text content to loaded text forom file just so we can see it
    textFileOutput.textContent = dictionary;
    
    // splits into array based on where a dot and a space is found
    // in this case ["Apple;blabla", "Pear; blah blah", "Banana; blahblie."]
    // we can remove the . at the end as well as the extra spaces later
    const definitionArray = dictionary.split('. ');

    for (const definitionPair of definitionArray) {
      // split defintion word;definition into ["word", "definition"]
      let splitDefinition = definitionPair.split(';');
      let word = splitDefinition[0]; // word will be the 0th item in splitDefinition
      let definition = splitDefinition[1]; // definition will be the 1st item in splitDefinition

      // we can add the words and definitions to an object so they can be accessed easily.
      // trim to remove whitespace + toLowerCase so it is lower case
      // we make it lower case so that when searching, we can lower the input and assert with that

      // the .replace(/[^_\W]+/g), ' ') replaces non alphanumeric characters with a space,
      // any spaces on either side will get remove due to the trim()
      
      // e.g. defintionObject['apple'] = 'blabla';
      definitionObject[word.trim().toLowerCase()] = definition.replace(/\W+/g, ' ').trim();
    }
        // Listen for whenever the text a key is pressed whilst in search box
    // if there is a result, return it, else clear
    
    // may want to replace this with a button that is pressed and then calls the function rather than every keyup
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    // check search input after trimming and lowering if it exists in the definition object
    // ("  Banana  " becomes "banana")
    // show definition if found, else empty the definition
      if (definitionObject[searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase()]) {
                definitionOutput.textContent = definitionObject[searchInput.value.trim().toLowerCase()];
      } else {
        definitionOutput.textContent = '';
      }
    });
});
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; height: fit-content; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Search from dictionary</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="textFileInput" name="textFileInput" type="file">
    <p>
     Loaded text so we can be sure the text is loaded correctly: 
    </p>
    <textarea id="textFileOutput" readonly></textarea>

    Word to search: <input id="searchInput" name="searchInput" type="text">
    <p>
    Definition: <span id="definitionOutput"></span>
    </p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

You need to load the file. You can use [fetch for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49680132/295783)

```js
const defFile = `Apple;blabla. Pear; blah blah. Banana; blahblie.`
const pairs = defFile.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)+; ?([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)+\./g)
const dl = document.getElementById("def")
const search = document.getElementById("search");
dl.innerHTML = pairs.map(pair => {
  const [dd, dt] = pair.split(";")
  return `<dd class="hide">${dd.trim()}</dd><dt  class="hide">${dt.trim()}</dt>`
}).join("");

search.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const s = this.value.toLowerCase();
  const dds = dl.querySelectorAll("dd");
  dds.forEach(dd => {
    const show = s && dd.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(s);
    dd.classList.toggle("hide", !show)
    dd.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide", !show)
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" />
<dl id="def"></dl>
```