Reload local file in JavaScript
I am a javascript novice. I mainly write code in c# so I'm every green at this.
I'm attempting to embed a PowerBI embedded report into a WPF application. I can do this, I have the report showing correctly and the data refreshing on a timer.
However the access token which is loaded with the page expires after a period of time.
I'm updating the token into a local file and reading that local file when the HTML page loads.
I don't want to have to reload the HTML page in the WPF web control to refresh the access token, I want to reload the file's contents and update the PowerBI access token in live use.
When I attempt to reload the new token on a timer, the variable holding the token doesn't update. It's still using the new token.
How can I reload the contents of the 'data.json' file to update the PowerBI 'report.setAccessToken'?
see "myMethod".
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Power BI </title>
    <!-- Include Power BI JavaScript library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="embedContainer" style="height: 1080px;"></div>
    <script src="app.js" async></script>

    <!-- File which contains the access token -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json" id="data"></script> 

</body>
</html>

app.js
let loadedResolve, reportLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => { loadedResolve = res; });
let renderedResolve, reportRendered = new Promise((res, rej) => { renderedResolve = res; });

models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

function embedPowerBIReport() {
    
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data)
    let accessToken = mydata[0].accessToken;

    // Read embed URL
    let embedUrl = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxxxx";

    // Read report Id
    let embedReportId = "xxxx";

    // Read embed type from radio
    let tokenType = "Bearer";

    // We give All permissions to demonstrate switching between View and Edit mode and saving report.
    let permissions = models.Permissions.All;

    // Create the embed configuration object for the report
    let config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: permissions,
        settings: {
            panes: {
                filters: {
                    visible: false
                },
                pageNavigation: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            bars: {
                statusBar: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("loaded");

    // report.on will add an event handler
    report.on("loaded", function () {
        loadedResolve();
        report.off("loaded");
    });

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("error");

    report.on("error", function (event) {
        console.log(event.detail);
    });

    // report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
    report.off("rendered");

    // report.on will add an event handler
    report.on("rendered", function () {
        renderedResolve();
        report.off("rendered");
    });

    window.setInterval(function () {
        report.refresh();
    }, 30 * 1000);

}

setInterval(myMethod, 20000);

function myMethod( )
{
     var mydata = JSON.parse(data)
     accessToken = mydata[0].accessToken;
     report.setAccessToken(accessToken);
     
     
     alert(mydata[0].accessToken);

}

async function loadReport() {

    embedPowerBIReport();
    
    await reportLoaded;

    await reportRendered;
    
}

loadReport();

data.json
data = '[{"accessToken" : "xxxxxxx"}]';


data.json not JSON, it's JavaScript. JSON is just the data, without the variable assignment. Instead of loading it as a script, make it a real JSON file and use AJAX to fetch it.

I learnt more about JS and decided to create a web socket connection between my WFP desktop application and the JS loading and refreshing the report.
The socket server gets a new token when the JS queries it. The JS then updates the token used by PowerBI.
It's a POC at the moment, code to be improved but this is the working example.
C#
public class LocalWebSocketServer
{
    public async Task StartServer(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://{ipAddress}:{port}/");
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server started. Waiting for connections...");

        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
            if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                ProcessWebSocketRequest(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessWebSocketRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
        WebSocket socket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;

        // Handle incoming messages
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                string receivedMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {receivedMessage}");

                var r = await EmbedService.GetEmbedParams(ConfigValidatorService.WorkspaceId, ConfigValidatorService.ReportId);

                Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {r.EmbedToken.Token}");
                string messageback = r.EmbedToken.Token;
                byte[] messagebackBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageback);
                await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messagebackBytes), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            }
            else if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
}

JS
//the token that will be used to authenticate the account
let authToken;

//the socket that will be used to communicate with the server
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

//checks if report is loaded - defines flow control on what do to when the auth token is received
let isReportLoaded = false;

//when connected send a message to the server to get the auth token
socket.onopen = function (e) {
   console.log("Connection established");
   socket.send("GET");
   console.log("GET sent");
}

//token update interval - every 15 minutes
setInterval(function() {
    socket.send("GET");
}, 900*1000);


//when a message is received from the server, set the auth token and load the report - also update the auth token if the report is already loaded
socket.onmessage = function (event) {

    authToken = event.data;
    console.log("Token set: " + event.data);

    if (isReportLoaded === false)
    {
        loadReport();
    } else {
    report.setAccessToken(event.data);   
    }

};


//load the report   
async function loadReport() {

 embedPowerBIReport();
 
 await reportLoaded;
 console.log("Report loaded");

 await reportRendered;
 console.log("Report Rendered");
 
 isReportLoaded = true;

}


How are you refreshing the access token?
Assuming you are using an HTTP request to get and store the token I'd recommend making that request in the JS code instead of separately and storing the result in a file. If you were to get the access code right as you need to use it there is no reason it'd ever be expired. If you need guidance on in browser HTTP request in JS I'd follow this posts accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

I'm refreshing the access token via the C# app which is hosting the page. The file is a local file, loaded from the hard disk

Is there any way you could do the refresh in JS? If not I'd use JQuery to load the data at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable
